# Solving for the roots of a polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

Suppose we have a polynomial of the form:

$$-x^3+3x^2+9x-27=0$$

Is there an easy way to find the solutions of $x$? I know that they will be factors of $27$, so I begin by factoring $27$ into $1,3,9,27$. I found that $1$ is not a root and $3$ is, so I know that the equation has a factored term $(x-3)$. However, solving the equation using $9$ and $27$ is very tedious and error-prone by hand. Is there a way I can easily find the roots here?

Comment: See [long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division).

Comment: I see you already asked 8 questions. Some were answered, some were not. In the answers where you recieved answers, you are expected to either accept one of them or explain why it is not the answer you are looking for. Consider this a warning and start to behave as expected for the site. If you do not, you will be flagged and you questions will, once the community realizes what you are doing, no longer be answered.

Comment: @5xum In all of the questions I've received answers (3 of them, apart from this one), I've accepted the answers. The other 6 questions do not have any answers...so what exactly am I being flagged for?

Comment: @jacob You are not being flagged for anything, since you accepted the answers now. At the time of my writing, you you have not accepted the answer to your previous question (or at least it has not been registered yet).

Comment: @5xum Even so, I posted that question ~30 minutes ago. Other users could have still posted answers which I could have chosen to accept from. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: @Jacob I do apologize, my warning was premature. But let me just explain myself: I saw a question in which a new user asked about how to calculate a characteristic polynomial, and a second question posted later about finding the roots of that polynomial. This second question means that the user *found* the characteristic polynomial, meaning one of the answers he got was good for him, but not accepted. And too many times, that means the user is behaving inapropriately for the site. I am glad to know I misjudged you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

We have

$-(-x^3+3x^2+9x-27)$

$=x^3+3^3-3x(x+3)$

$=(x+3)(x^2-3x+3^2)-3x(x+3)$

$=(x+3)\{x^2-3x+3^2-3x\}$

$=(x+3)(x-3)^2$

Answer (score 0):

Since you know that a factor is (x-3), you can use long division or synthetic division to find that the other two roots can be found by the equation f(x)=(-x^2)+9=0.  Which of course implies that x^2=9 and x= 3 or -3. So there are in total two roots at 3 and one root at -3.